# Duvida sobre google tanslate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Boa tarde, estou com uma duvida relativamente ao google translate, implementei o o google translate no meu web site, eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de esta barra nao aparecer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'pt', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT}, 'google_translate_element');

    }

    function triggerHtmlEvent(element, eventName) {
      var event;
      if (document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
      } else {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.eventType = eventName;
        element.fireEvent('on' + event.eventType, event);
      }
    }
    jQuery('.lang-select').click(function() {
      var theLang = jQuery(this).attr('data-lang');
      jQuery('.goog-te-combo').val(theLang);

      //alert(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
      window.location = jQuery(this).attr('href');
      location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia amigo, tente isso:

```
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
  display: none !important;
} 
body {
  top: 0px !important; 
}
```

Não pude testar mas acho que vai resolver

Comment: muito agradecido, ajudou bastante. obrigado

Comment: Por nada amigo !

Comment: mais 1 questão que talvez me saiba responder, esta a ver o boato de mostrar original, ou seja eu nao tenho essa barra visivel, tenho por imagens, a minha questão é se da para programar um botão para monstar orignal, por exemplo clicar na bandeira de portugal e a linguagem do web site volta á linguagem original.